# why I need public word when i live my Laravel project

Tags: laravel, url, assets

hello Laravel developers!
I  am stuck with Laravel assets URLs.

```
 <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

this link works fine on localhost.
But why i need to add "public" when i upload it to server like

```
 <link href="/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I moved app/public/index.php to app/index.php and make changes in server.php and index.php accordingly. Rest is the working fine. issue is only with assets urls.
Similarly, the class

```
.edu-home-hero-area {
    background: url(/assets/images/curve.webp) !important;
}
```

works fine on localhost but when i upload it, it does not work i need to change it to

```
.edu-home-hero-area {
        background: url(/public/assets/images/curve.webp) !important;
    }
```

please have a look

```
https://pdaofficial.com/
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: you need to redirect all requests to the public/ directory if you are using apache you can do it  .htaccess with mod_rewrite

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if i understand your question completely but you should not be moving public folder files some where else. why not reference your css or js assets using asset function. It will directly point to public folder and look for build.css inside css folder.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/build.css') }}">
```

Comment: whole project is ready and i can not make big changes to that project.